# Adding a shebang causes No such file or directory error when running my python script

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to run a python script. It works fine when I run it:

```
python2.5 myscript.py inpt0
```

The problem starts when I add a shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.5
```

Result in:

```
$ myscript.py inpt0
: No such file or directory
```

Try 2:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.5
```

Result in:

```
$ myscript.py inpt0
: bad interpreter: No such file or directoryon2.5
```

When I run them directly in the terminal they both work just fine:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.5
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Feb  9 2009, 12:50:32)
[GCC 3.2.3 20030502 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

$ /usr/bin/env python2.5
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Feb  9 2009, 12:50:32)
[GCC 3.2.3 20030502 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Any hints on how to make this work with shebang?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I had similar problems and it turned out to be problem with line-endings. You use windows/linux/mac line endings?

Edit: forgot the script name, but as OP says, it's `dos2unix <filename>`

Comment: If your file is UTF8, make sure there is no [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)