# Execute python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have been working with Python for a short while and have created some programs, Im just setting up a third Raspberry Pi with Raspian Jessie.  On the other two Pis I didn't run into an issue, but on this one I can't get my Python script to execute the same way.

The first line of the file has the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I git cloned the repo and went to the directory and did:

```
chmod +x script.py
```

but when I try to `./script.py` it doesnt work.  From the Desktop it asks if the file should be executed and when I choose execute in terminal it closes and does not execute.  I tried placing script.py in

```
/usr/local/bin
```

but that has no effect.  If I do:

```
python script.py
```

it works fine.

The only difference between the Pis is the first two are headless and this new one has the Pixel desktop environment.

Comment: What do you see if you run `/usr/bin/env python -V` in your terminal?

Comment: I see
Python 2.7.9

Comment: Well, that means that `env` is correctly locating your `python` executable.

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean?  When you run `./script.py`, nothing happens?  Do you not see any output or errors?

Comment: I get : No such file or directory

Comment: The file may have DOS line-endings and (most) linux shells don't like that.  Try `dos2unix script.py`.  Resources: http://stackoverflow.com/q/531382 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19764710

Comment: OK thats a possibility, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably made the file on a Windows PC and it got saved with [DOS-style line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).  The linux shell (bash) doesn't like that and gets confused when trying to execute the script file.

Try to convert the file to UNIX line endings:

```
dos2unix script.py
```

<sub>You may need to do `apt-get install dos2unix`.</sub>

As a tip, you can use an editor/IDE in Windows that supports/saves as UNIX-style line endings to avoid this.